# fetch data contiuously from a url

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xml

```
<?php

 $url='http://apidintegra.tkfweb.com/apid/request?method=getListingData&mk=186;6&pk=12,0,1;3,1,1;33,537,1;33,579,1&psk=none&ik1=86103141,344,333&ci=iD2&ui=SG31378-narnapid01&id=893238542';  
function get_data($url)
{

$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $data;
}
$xml_data=(get_data($url));
```

I want to dynamically fetch data from the url which I did,the url being 
    stored in $url, now I want to continuously fetch data from this url 
    and store it in $url,this is actually stock exchange API,which needs to be 
    constantly refreshed.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Put this function on cron shedule

Comment: @ Mayank Pandeyz .How to do that?Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Use cronjobs if you have server with root access, more about crons here: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/
If you have hosting, ask for support, most hostings have custom schedule systems which works like cronjobs.

Answer (score 0):

First, Login to UNIX/Linux system.

Type the following command to enter cronjob:

```
$ crontab -e
```

Each cronjob has the following syntax:

```
# +---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  +------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  +---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  +------- month (1 - 12)
# |  |  |  |  +---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)
# |  |  |  |  |
  *  *  *  *  *  command to be executed
```

Ex:

To execute myscript.php every 1 hour do the following:

```
# crontab -e
00 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/john/myscript.php
```

Run the php script using URL from the crontab

If your php script can be invoked using an URL, you can lynx, or curl, or wget to setup your crontab as shown below.

The following script executes the php script (every hour) by calling the URL using the lynx text browser. Lynx text browser by default opens a URL in the interactive mode. However, as shown below, the -dump option in lynx command, dumps the output of the URL to the standard output.

```
00 * * * * lynx -dump http://www.thegeekstuff.com/myscript.php
```

[Reference](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/php-cron-job)